# Twenty-one in total

Tags: riddle, word

**I'm looking for a single word.**

---

- *in the M*
- *on the TL and BR*
- *on the TL, in the M and BR*
- *on the TL, TR, BL and BR*
- *on the TL, TR, in the M, BL and BR*
- *on the TL, TR, ML, MR, BL and BR*

---

**What Am I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This describes:

> the positions of **pips** on a **die**.

In each case, the letters stand for:

> T = top, M = middle, B = bottom;
>  L = left, R = right.
>
>  And the 'bullet point' instructions are actually telling us where to place the *dots* (i.e. pips) that the bullet points resemble! (e.g. The first instruction should be read as '*a dot* in the Middle' [to form the '1' side], and the second as '*a dot* on the Top Left and Bottom Right' [to form the '2' side], etc.)
>
>  The precise patterns and how they relate to the text can be seen in the image below:
>
>  [image: Annotated die faces]

Comment: Well done! The rot13(ohyyrgf jnf npghnyyl cneg bs gur chmmyr, erfrzoyvat gur cvcf.)

Comment: @Prim3numbah Ah yes, that's very nice :)

Comment: might also want to mention how the title is related